# Derivative of product of polynomials: why does it suffice to check Leibniz for monomials?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, polynomials

I'm reading I.N. Herstein's Topics in Algebra, Second Edition. in one of the chapters about polynomials, i was not able to understand a proof of it,

> Let $$f(x) = a_0 + a_1x + \dots+ a_n x^n \in F[x]$$ where $F$ is a field, and $$f'(x) = a_1 + 2 a_2x + \dots + n a_n x^{n-1}.$$
>
> Verify that
> \begin{align}
> \left(f(x) g(x)\right)' = f'(x)g(x) + f(x) g'(x).
> \label{op.eq.leibniz}
> \tag{1}
> \end{align}

To prove this, it is written, "It's enough only to consider the special case $f(x) = x^i, g(x)= x^j$". I don't understand why they don't have to prove it generally.

Comment: If you have it for monomials $x^i$, it immediately follows for sums of monomials.

Comment: that's what i am not able to understand

Comment: Hint: Assume that \eqref{op.eq.leibniz} holds whenever $f$ and $g$ are monomials. Now, let $f$ and $g$ be polynomials. Write $f = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^j$ and $g = \sum_{j=0}^m b_j x^j$, and plug these two equalities into both sides of \eqref{op.eq.leibniz}. What do you get? Note that you can move the summation sign as well as the $a_i$ and $b_j$ factors out of the derivatives, since $\left(f+g\right)^\prime = f^\prime + g^\prime$ and $\left(af\right)^\prime = af^\prime$ for $a \in F$.

Comment: You can easily prove that $(f + g)'(x) = f'(x) + g'(x) $ and $(af(x))' = af'(x)$ for polynomials in $F[x]$ and $a$ in $F$, so this differential operator is linear. That reduces the general problem to the monomial problem.

Answer (score 2):

The map $\Phi\colon F[x]\times F[x]\to F[x]$, $(f,g)\mapsto (fg)'-f'g-fg'$ is bilinear (i.e., clearly(?), $\Phi(cf,g))=c\Phi(f,g)$ for $c\in F$, and $\Phi(f_1+f_2,g)=\Phi(f_1,g)+\Phi(f_2,g)$, and the corresponding equalities for the second parameter follow from the symmetry of $\Phi$, $\Phi(f,g)=\Phi(g,f)$). We want to show that $\Phi(f,g)=0$ for all $f$ and $g$. Now since each $f$ (and $g$) is a linear combination of monomials $x^i$ and $\Phi$ is bilinear, it suffices to show that $\Phi(x^i,x^j)=0$ for all $i,j$:
$$ \Phi(f,g)=\Phi(\sum_i a_ix^i,\sum_j b_jx^j)=\sum_{i,j}a_ib_j\underbrace{\Phi(x^i,x^j)}_{=0}=0.$$